# Issue with custom Margin and StrokeDashArray dependency property

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties

I have a custom control and a line inside the control. The width of the line should come out of the control.
 If I give the Margin in the style itself say -20,0,-20,0 , then it works.

But if I bind it through a dependency property  then it does not. Similarly, if I bind StrokeDashArray, also does not work.

I have pasted my dependency property and the line style below.
 Can someone please help me how to fix this?

Removed the custom property bindings to look the code simpler. ClipToBounds false does not work as well :-(

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Grid>
     <Border ClipToBounds="False" Background="LightGray"
                    BorderBrush="Red"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    Height="150"
                     Width="200">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Rectangle ClipToBounds="False" Grid.Row="1" 
                          Margin="-30,0,-30,0"
                          StrokeThickness="2"
                          Stroke="Green"
                          StrokeDashArray="2"
                               Width="200"
                               Height="1"></Rectangle>

            <Rectangle Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
   Height="20" Width="200"></Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</Window>


    Thanks & Regards,
```

Comment: The type of your LineStrokeDashedArray property should be `DoubleCollection`, not `double`. That said, a horizontal line that stretches to the parent width is easier created by a Rectangle with zero Height than a Line with bound X2 property.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used rectangle but negative margin does not work. But if I give the positive values the mar works. I think the problem is with the control hierarchy but not sure at all. I have pasted my code below, can you get where I am doing wrong? I want to paste the code but it says the number of lines are more :-(

Comment: Don't put code in comments. It's unreadable. Edit your question instead.

Comment: You mean by the negative Margin the Rectangle should extend beyond the bounds of the templated control? Maybe set the controls `ClipToBounds` property to false.

Comment: Clip to bounds does not work as well :-( Update the code to look simple. Can you have a look at it once. Thanks.

Comment: I meant to set ClipToBounds on the parent control., e.g. the Grid.

Comment: :-( unfortunately, this also does not work